# How do I return the flotter geolocator position value? (programming language : dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making an app using a flutter.

I'm trying to save the position value to a variable using the geolocator library, but I can't print the value due to the error below.

Please look at the code below and tell me how to save the return location value in a variable. Thank you.

```html
/* Convert to location using Geolocator */
Future<Position> _getLocation() async {
    return Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low)
        .then((location) {
      return location;
    });
  }

/* run app */

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _getUser();
    print(_getLocation());
    
    - omit below -
    
/*  =============================== */
/*  Output value when the app runs  */
/*  Instance of 'Future<Position>'  */
/*  =============================== */
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are trying to print promise but not position. Did you try ```print(await _getLocation());```?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Future<Position> _getLocation() async {
          return await Geolocator()
              .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
        }

Position userPosition = await _getLocation();
print(userPosition);
```

Comment: If I insert await into the Widget build class, an error appears with the red underline.

Comment: ERROR LOG : The await expression can only be used in an async function.

Comment: You shouldn't be using these in your widget class. Define userPosition variable in state class and call _getLocation() in initState() method of your stateful widget. Methods and values in widget build get fired everytime when widget is rebuilt and it's not a good approach.